# How to connect Orange-Widgets in a Python script

Tags: python, orange

I would like to use Orange widgets not in the Orange canvas but in my own program. In the main functions of some widgets it is shown how to put data into a widget. For example:

```
ow = OWScatterPlot()
ow.set_data(Orange.data.Table('iris'))
```

But unfortunately I can't find out how to connect Inputs and Outputs of two widgets. I had expected something like this:

```
ow1 = OWSelectRows()
ow1.set_data(Table("iris"))
ow2 = OWScatterPlot()
ow2.Inputs.data=ow1.Outputs.matching_data
```

But no data reaches ow2. 
In the canvas it is done just by dragging the link from one widget to another. Does anybody know how it is done in a Python script?

Comment: Since you seem to know Python, did you check what happens in Orange source?

Comment: I just found the function self.Outputs.matching_data.send(data) but I can't find out where it is sent.to.

Answer (score 0):

Orange have a SignalManager runing in the background, which handle widgets inputs and outputs. So if you would like to transfer your data from one widget to another without canvas, you should do something like this:

```
from orangecanvas.application.canvasmain import *
from Orange.data import Table
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from orangewidget.tests.base import DummySignalManager
from Orange.widgets.data.owtable import OWDataTable
from WindowForWidgets import WindowForWidgets


def App():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    signal_manager = DummySignalManager()
    window_for_widgets = WindowForWidgets

    data = Table('iris')

    ow1 = OWDataTable()
    ow1.signalManager = signal_manager
    getattr(ow1, ow1.Inputs.data.handler)(data) # you may replace this with: ow1.set_data(data)
    ow1.handleNewSignals()
    window_for_widgets = WindowForWidgets(ow1, data, signal_manager)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

App()
```

I used WindowForWidgets to show first widget and detect when the widget is closed (closeEvent method). Then we transfer the data from the first widget to second with signal manager. Here is the code for WindowForWidgets:

```
from Orange.widgets.visualize.owscatterplot import OWScatterPlot
from orangecanvas.application.canvasmain import *

class WindowForWidgets(QMainWindow):
    WINDOW_WIDTH = 400
    WINDOW_HEIGHT = 250

    def __init__(self, widget, data,  signal_manager):
        super(WindowForWidgets, self).__init__()
        self.widget = widget
        self.data = data
        self.signal_manager = signal_manager
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setCentralWidget(self.widget)
        self.show()

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        ow2 = OWScatterPlot()
        getattr(ow2, ow2.Inputs.data.handler)(self.signal_manager.get_output(self.widget, "Selected Data"))
        ow2.show()
```

This code will transfer selected data from the first widget to second. If we want to transfer all data we need to change the line in closeEvent method from:

```
getattr(ow2, ow2.Inputs.data.handler)(self.signal_manager.get_output(self.widget, "Selected Data"))
```

to:

```
getattr(ow2, ow2.Inputs.data.handler)(self.signal_manager.get_output(self.widget, "Data"))
```